# Deleting from tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application

I have an old C# console application that I'm currently upgrading to use Entity Framework (latest version) code first.

I have 20+ tables that will be created in the database.

One of my methods is

```
static void DeleteModelInDb(Model pdModel, ExporterContext db) {
    string[] tables = new string[] { "PD_COLUMN", "PD_COLUMN_EXTENDED", "PD_COLUMNRULE", "PD_COLUMNSOURCE", "PD_DB_PACKAGE", "PD_DB_PACKAGE_PROC_PARAMETER", "PD_DB_PACKAGE_PROCEDURE", "PD_DB_PACKAGE_TYPE", "PD_DB_PACKAGE_VARIABLE", "PD_DIAGRAM", "PD_DIAGRAM_TABLE", "PD_DOMAIN", "PD_DOMAIN_VALUES", "PD_INDEX", "PD_INDEX_COLUMN", "PD_JOIN", "PD_MODEL", "PD_MODEL_EXTENDED", "PD_MODEL_CHANGES", "PD_MODELSOURCE", "PD_PACKAGE", "PD_REFERENCE", "PD_RULE", "PD_TABLE", "PD_TABLE_EXTENDED", "PD_TABLE_CHANGES", "PD_TABLE_KEY", "PD_TABLE_KEY_COLUMN", "PD_TABLESOURCE", "PD_VIEW", "PD_VIEWCOLUMN", "PD_VIEWSOURCE" };

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("definition of con...");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();
    foreach (string table in tables)
    {
        com.CommandText = "DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE MODEL_CODE = '" + pdModel.Code + "'";
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    com.Dispose();
}
```

I would like to do something like this using Entity framework. But I don't want to write this delete code for every table.

```
var x = (from y in db.PdColumn
         where y.ModelCode == pdModel.Code
         select y).FirstOrDefault();
db.PdColumn.Remove(x);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Any reason for doing it with ef ?

Comment: It was decided EF will be the technology used in this case - not much I can do about it. Nevertheless I would still like to know if this is even possible using EF

Comment: `db` is your `DbContext` right?

Comment: @ershoaib - correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through tables in Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192805/looping-through-tables-in-entity-framework-6)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to abstract over the deletion code by having all the relevant entities implement an interface with the ModelCode property, then make a generic method for deleting (I am assuming that ModelCode is of type string below):

```
interface IEntityWithCode {
   string ModelCode {get;}
}

void DeleteFromDbSet<T>(DBSet<T> dbset, string modelcode) where T: IEntityWithCode {
  var x = (from y in dbset
           where y.ModelCode == modelcode
           select y).FirstOrDefault();
  dbset.Remove(x);
}
```

Since C# does not support variance for classes, I don't think you can have a loop over a list of dbsets in your new DeleteModelInDb method without resorting to nasty reflection hacks, so it will have to look something like this

```
void DeleteModelInDb(YourDbContext context, string modelcode) {
  DeleteFromDbSet(context.SomeTable, modelcode);
  DeleteFromDbSet(context.SomeOtherTable, modelcode);
  //and so on
}
```

(Disclaimer: The code is not tested as I don't have an EF core setup handy ATM)

Comment: I'm getting CS0120 on DeleteFromDbSet(context.SomeTable, modelcode);
I'm not sure whats wrong.

Comment: Make sure the two methods are in the same class or make DeleteFromDbSet static